# Ubuntu dist update but os-release file and lsb-release file mismatch version

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 21.10, lsb-release

After upgrading my laptop from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to 21.10 using the command `# update-manager -c` it appears that my OS thinks it is still in 20.04. Now it tells me that it can do the update to Ubuntu 21.10 which I've previously done. I'm already on that version. If I do the update, I get a fail message but no explanation.

content of etc/lsb-release file:

[picture of the content of etc/lsb-release file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y13ah.png)

content of etc/os-release file:

[picture of the content of etc/os-release file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOxrY.png)

The content of usr/lib/os-release file is the same as this one.

It's the about section of Ubuntu settings. As we can see, GNOME updates well but the OS name is still in 20.04.

[picture of version content in about from settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcYoS.png)

If someone has an idea to fix this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: How did you do this? There's not a supported upgrade path from 20.04 to 21.10...

Comment: @Nmath I think there is? `dist-upgrade` had the same effect for me (without the bugs, that is), after I enabled updating to non-LTS versions in the settings.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat -- No. It's not supported. Release upgrades are only supported from one release to the next. All of the releases between 20.04 and 21.10 are EOL, so those release upgrades are dually unsupported. You can upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 because they are both LTS releases, but this upgrade will not be offered until the 22.04.1 point release.  See: https://askubuntu.com/a/20668

Comment: @Nmath I don't know, in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades i change prompt to normal to update on the last one and that's all, i touch nothing else. It's ubuntu who ask me if i wanted to install this version. I followed this tuto https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-ubuntu-20-04-21-04-to-21-10

Comment: Well unfortunately that blog post is wrong about skipping over releases. It is also outdated. Random blog posts are not always reliable sources of information. Every comment indicates problems... You can continue to troubleshoot this, but if you can't find a solution, reinstall the OS. Honestly, you made a bad choice-- it really makes little sense to me that you would try to upgrade from 20.04 to 21.10 in the first place. Either upgrade every 6-9 months every time there is a new standard release, or you can upgrade from LTS to LTS release. **21.10 is going to be EOL in fewer than 30 days...**

Comment: @Nmath thanks, next time i'll be aware of that and won't do it. I don't have a lot of knowledge in Ubuntu. I learned something today. I'll probably reinstall the OS soon.

Comment: Ubuntu releases have *supported* a LTS to *latest* non-LTS (*in the next cycle*) for some time, ie. when 20.10 reached EOL, 20.04 users could upgrade to 21.04, then when it reached EOL they could upgrade to 21.10; so it's a *currently* supported upgrade path (*it gets CI tested but not a lot of QA testing on supported releases; but you will find it on http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/ for QA late in the cycle too*). The usage of `dist-upgrade` though confuses me; as it won't perform any *release-upgrades* type features; and I'd too stick to official Ubuntu upgrade documentation (*not 3rd party blogs*)

Comment: Have you rebooted?  In your case I'd login at text terminal (*I don't see mention  if it's a server or desktop; pictures imply desktop to me*) then `sudo apt update` and read the output ensuring it all looks what you'd expect for a *focal* or 20.04 system, then assuming it looked good with no warnings or missing lines (*I may also check mirror if you're using one & switch to main archive, but optional*), I'd then perform `sudo apt full-upgrade` to see if all packages available are installed and let them install (*I may switch off mirror if you're uisng one to main archive if nothing seen*)

Comment: @guiverc yes i already reboot many time and do sudo apt update and full-upgrade but it find nothing to update and I'm on a desktop. I don't really understand what do the QA and which one i should download.

Comment: @karel thanks for the link but i haven't the same problem. My OS find a new release, but it find the release i'm on. I upgrade from 20.04 to 21.10 and my OS think is still in 20.04 so he tell me it can upgrade to 21.10 again but it failed if i retry to upgrade

Comment: OK, there's no harm done. No one has currently close voted your question for that reason.